# Adding Width property moving content to the left

Tags: html, css, alignment, width

I have already provided margin for the main body.
main{margin-left:200px; margin-right: 200px; text-align: center}

As I wanted to show the texts in two lines instead of one line, I added width property in style.

.p{font-size: 12px; width: 200px}

This line of could serves the purpose of showing the paragraph in two lines but it moves the text to the left.

Then even if I try

.p{font-size: 12px; width: 200px; text-align: center; align-items: center};

The paragraph won't budge. It stays in left, out of alignment.

How Can I solve this problem.

Comment: Could please provide a snippet code using Snippet button in the editor. It would make it easier to understand what you are trying to achieve. Also if you had a graphic representation of your desired results that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

I don‘t really understand what you want to archive. You could use a framework for example bootstrap, it‘s easy to learn and understand and also responsive.